# How to fix about Error in proxfun.igraph using R

Tags: r, social-networking

```
result_cn<- proxfun(g, method = "cn", value = c("edgelist"))

Error in proxfun.igraph(g, method = "pa", value = c("edgelist")) : graph has to be undirected and connected
```

It is what error looks like.
I use package proxfun in r to calculate some SNA variables.
I guess the error is that some vertices are isolate.

What suggestion for me? 
How do I remove the isolated vertices or I can do something else?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me.

```
g = as.undirected(g)
is.connected(g)

result_cn <- proxfun(g, method = "cn", value = c("edgelist"))
```